# Save the spacing in the source

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to save spacing in my table. This is the source:

```
\texttt{
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \textbf{input} & \textbf{output}\\
 \hline
7&      1      \\
 &     212     \\
 &    32123    \\
 &   4321234   \\
 &  543212345  \\
 & 65432123456 \\
 &7654321234567\\
 & 65432123456 \\
 &  543212345  \\
 &   4321234   \\
 &    32123    \\
 &     212     \\
 &      1     \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

And it generates a table like this:

[image: output]

But I need it to save the spacing as seen in the source. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this (what of course not preserves spacing of the input, but tunes the output):

[image: centerit]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}||>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
 \hline
 \textbf{input} & \textbf{output}\\
 \hline
7&      1      \\
 &     212     \\
 &    32123    \\
 &   4321234   \\
 &  543212345  \\
 & 65432123456 \\
 &7654321234567\\
 & 65432123456 \\
 &  543212345  \\
 &   4321234   \\
 &    32123    \\
 &     212     \\
 &      1     \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

*Update:* If you need the output (header) left-aligned use `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{output}}`.